# Why extend from eventEmitter when the methods are never used (hexo-cli)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hexo

Why have `class Context` extend `EventEmitter` at all ? in the package hexoc-cli i don't see the methods of `EventEmitter` used at all, so why extend from this class ?

I see context is defined [**HERE**](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-cli/blob/master/lib/context.ts) like so :-

```
class Context extends EventEmitter { // code here }
```

and then ofcourse being used in the index(hexo.ts) file like so **[LINK](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-cli/blob/master/lib/hexo.ts)** :-

```
function entry(cwd = process.cwd(), args) {
  args = camelCaseKeys(
      args || minimist(process.argv.slice(2), 
      { string: ['_', 'p', 'path', 's' ,'slug'] 
  }));

  let hexo = new Context(cwd, args);
  // more code here
}
```